# np.nan become None in GeoSeries

Tags: python, geopandas, nonetype

It looks like GeoPandas doesn't like `np.nan`, at least in my version, `0.8.1`. When I pass a `np.nan` into a GeoSeries it becomes a `None` and I don't know to get the `np.nan` back.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point as pt
import numpy as np

lt = [np.nan, np.nan, pt([1,2]), pt([0,0])]
ser = gpd.GeoSeries(lt)

# Somehow the first two elements of ser became None
ser[0] is None #True
np.isnan(ser[0]) #TypeError

# I don't even know how to put a np.nan in the GeoSeries
ser[0] = np.nan # This doesn't work
# These tests still give the same results
ser[0] is None #True
np.isnan(ser[0]) #TypeError
```

Am I missing something? Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to get a `np.nan` within a `GeoSeries`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation there are two sections which answer your question.

From the section about [GeoSeries](https://geopandas.org/data_structures.html#geoseries)

> A `GeoSeries` is essentially a vector where each entry in the vector is a set of shapes corresponding to one observation.
>
> geopandas has three basic classes of geometric objects (which are actually shapely objects):
>
> 1. Points / Multi-Points
> 2. Lines / Multi-Lines
> 3. Polygons / Multi-Polygons
>
> Note that all entries in a GeoSeries need not be of the same geometric type, although certain export operations will fail if this is not the case.

From the section about [missing and empty geometries](https://geopandas.org/missing_empty.html)

> **Missing geometries** are unknown values in a `GeoSeries`. The scalar object (when accessing a single element of a GeoSeries) is the Python `None` object.

So the behavior is wanted by geopandas.

**Comment**

In the latest version it is possible to produce a `NaN`-value which is not recommended.

If your run `gpd.GeoSeries([np.nan, np.nan, pt([1,2]), pt([0,0])])`, then the resulting series is of type `GeoSeries`.

If you mix floats and points likes this `gpd.GeoSeries([10, np.nan, pt([1,2]), pt([0,0])])` the result is of type `Series` which is a fallback right now which contains a `NaN` value.

In `geopandas 0.8.0` this raises a warning: `You are passing non-geometry data to the GeoSeries constructor.` In future versions this will raise an error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not checked this since gpd 0.6, so thanks for pointing this out. I do not agree with this strategy and I would argue that, at least, it should throw a warning about changing the type from the original data. That is a different story, though. Thanks again